# Use common linq expression to avoid duplicate of entity to poco

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

How may I avoid to duplicate the code I use for mapping a database entity to a poco object?

Given this code:

```
private IQueryable<DummyExtended> Find()
{
    return (from dt in Entities.dummy_table
            select new DummyExtended
            {                           
                Description = dt.table_1.table_2.description,               
                Dummy = new Dummy 
                {
                    Name = d.name,
                    Notes = d.notes,
                    HelpText = d.help_text          
                }
            }).AsQueryable();

}
```

Can I create a common linq expression to be re-used for both methods?

```
private IQueryable<DummyExtended> Find()
{
    return (from dt in Entities.dummy_table
            select new DummyExtended
            {                           
                Description = dt.table_1.table_2.description,               
                Dummy = ...???
            }).AsQueryable();

}

private IQueryable<DummyAlsoExtended> FindAnother()
{
    return (from dt in Entities.dummy_table
            select new DummyAlsoExtended
            {                           
                InnerHtml = dt.table_html.description,              
                Dummy = ....??
            }).AsQueryable();

}
```

Example:

```
public static Expression<Func<dummy_table, Dummy>> EntityToPoco()
{
    return d => new Dummy 
    {
        Name = d.name,
        Notes = d.notes,
        HelpText = d.help_text
};
```

}

I can't quite get it right

```
....
Dummy = ExtensionClass.EntityToPoco()
```

Comment: I think you need to look into LINQKit and `.AsExpandable()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `dummy_table` which is a Enumerable or Queryable sequence of objects. Let's assume that the sequence contains objects of class `DummyTableElement`.

You showed, that if you have a `DummyTableElement` you know how to convert it into a `Dummy` object. You want to reuse this function to create other objects like `DummyExtended` and `DummyAlsoExtended`. If you want to do this LINQ-alike, it is best to create extension functions for it:

```
static class DummyTableElementExtensions
{
    public static Dummy ToDummy(this TableElement tableElement)
    {
        return new Dummy()
        {
             Name = tableElement.name,
             Notes = tableElement.notes,
             HelpText = tableElement.help_text     
        };
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can create similar functions to convert `TableElements` into `DummyExtended` and `DummyAlsoExtended`. They will be one-liners.

In the same extension class:

```
public static DummyExtended ToDummyExtended(this TableElement tableElement)
{
    return new DummyExtended()
    {
        Description = tableElement.table_1.table_2.description, 
        Dummy = tableElement.ToDummy(),              
    };
}
public static DummyAlsoExtended ToDummyAlsoExtended(this TableElement tableElement)
{
    return new DummyAlsoExtended
    {                           
        InnerHtml = tableElement.table_html.description,              
        Dummy = tableElement.ToDummy(),
    };
}
```

And once you've got these, you can create extension functions to convert any `IQueryable` of `TableElements`:

```
public static IQueryable<DummyExtended> ToDummyExtended(
    this IQueryable<TableElement> tableElements)
{
    return tableElements
        .Select(tableElement => tableelement.ToDummyExtended();
}
```

And a similar one-line function for `DummyAlsoExtended`.

Your `Find` function and `FindAnother` function will also be one-liners:

```
private IQueryable<DummyExtended> Find()
{
    return dummy_table.ToDummyExtended();
}

private IQueryable<DummyAlsoExtended> FindAnother()
{
    return dummy_table.ToDummyAlsoExtended();
}
```

I'm not sure why you wanted to use an expression in this. It doesn't seem that `DummyExtended` and `DummyAlsoExtended` are really similar, except that they both have a property `Dummy`.

One reason to parameterize the destination of your find function could be because you want to create anonymous classes in your Find function.

Again, once you've created `ToDummy` this will be a one-liner:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Find<TSource, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Select(sourceElement => resultSelector(sourceElement);
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var X = dummy_Table.find(tableElement => new
   {
      foo = tableElement.CalculateFoo(),
      bar = tableElement.CalculateBar(),
      Dummy = tableElement.ToDummy(),
   });
```

Comment: Custom (extension) methods are not supported inside LINQ to Entities expression tree though.